# How to obtain an object of type BaseType from an object of type that inherits from it?

Tags: vb.net, inheritance

Let's say I have:

```
Class Vehicle
    Public Property NumberOfWheels As Integer
End Class

Class Bicycle
    Inherits Vehicle

End Class
```

I do:

```
Dim b = New Bicycle() With {.NumberOfWheels = 2}
Dim v As Vehicle = CType(b, Vehicle)
```

and `v` is still `Bicycle` when I debug the code and hover the object with a mouse.
How can I obtain an object of type Vehicle from object of type Bicycle? Do I have to do it manually?

Comment: Why do you need to?  By definition, a `Bicycle` *is* a `Vehicle`.

Comment: I need it because I try to serialize the object and my WCF service expects `Vehicle`. I read about `KnownType` attribute, but it didn't work for me...

Comment: If the service asks for a `Vehicle` in it's contract, and you are passing it a `Bicycle`, that should work fine.  Something else is likely wrong.  To answer your original question, yes, you would need to do a little of the leg-work manually, so it's best, in this case, to fix the main issue rather than the symptom.

Comment: Are you calling the WCF service via the proxy class that is automatically generate by visual studio when you add the service reference?  In what way does it not work when you pass it a `Bicycle` object?

Comment: There was an error while trying to serialize parameter http://tempuri.org/:vehicle. The InnerException message was 'Type 'Website.Bicycle' with data contract name 'Bicycle:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Website' is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.'.  Please see InnerException for more details.

Comment: I am calling WCF service via the client class that I made myself (client and service implement the same contract interface)

Comment: So you are serializing the object yourself?  If so, how do you determine which type to serialize from?  Could you show the code for that?

Comment: I am not serializing myself. It's done automatically. I have a client : `Public Class CrmClient Inherits ClientBase(Of Contracts.ICrm)` where ICrm is the interface that defines the methods shared between the client and the server.

Answer (score 0):

I was gonna give you the obvious solution:

```
Class Bicycle
    Inherits Vehicle

    Public Shared Widening Operator CType(value As Bicycle) As Vehicle
        Return New Vehicle With {.NumberOfWheels = value.NumberOfWheels}
    End Operator

End Class
```

However that also pops a compiler error:

> Conversion operators cannot convert from a type to its base type

Doing a quick search on MSDN brings up the following explanation:

> At compile time, Visual Basic considers a predefined conversion to
>   exist from any reference type to any type in its inheritance
>   hierarchy, that is, any type from which it derives or which derives
>   from it. Such a conversion might fail at run time, but the compiler
>   cannot predict run-time results, so it allows any such conversion to
>   compile.

To cut a long story short, I think you need to implement `ISerializable` on `Vehicle` and provide a custom implementation for each class that derives from it.